# QT how to use templates on Designer Class

Tags: c++, qt, templates

Well, I'am kind of newbie on Qt so, I wanted to use templates on Qt but I couldn't find out how to do it,

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
template<typename T> class MainWindow;
}

template<typename T> class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I defined MainWindow w; like this and I used  tag on constructor and destructor but I'm gettin g:

> error: invalid use of template-name 'Ui::MainWindow' without an
>   argument list

How can I use templates on this ?

Comment: From which line do you get that error?

Comment: on this Ui::MainWindow *ui; in class of private field.

Comment: Well, isn't the error message pretty clear: you are missing `<T>` from that. Or whatever type you want.

Comment: Btw, note that `Ui::MainWindow` and `MainWindow` are totally different, separate classes. How did you manage to make `Ui::MainWindow` to be template class?

Comment: I tried that,but when I did this like Ui::MainWindow<T> *ui; I'm getting "Ui::MainWindow is not a template" error ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: There is no spesific thing I'm trying actually, i just wonder how can i use templates with qt, but isn't it weird whole programmers do not use templates with Q_OBJECT ? I think I'm gonna understand later.

Comment: It's because template isn't a class yet, it is just a template. But each QObject subclass has associated metaclass with single static instance, generated by *moc*. Trying to create those for specialized templates would get hairy, if not impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have:

```
namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}
```

Because Ui::MainWindow definition (in ui_Mainwindow.h) is generated by uic, and is not a template class.

---

The error after that you get, because `QObject` subclass can not be a template class... So I think you can not do what you want with templates.